# Export Data from Single/multiple Custom Grid Controls in Rally

Tags: rally

By Adding 4 Custom Grid Controls in a Single page with below multiple & Similar Queries I got “Aging Defects Report" for different Age groups (like “Defect <=30 Days / Defects Age - 31 to 60 Days / Defects Age 61-90 Days, etc.,)

Query: (((((ScheduleState != "Completed") And (ScheduleState != "Accepted")) And (State != "Closed")) and (CreationDate >= "today-30")) AND (CreationDate <= "today"))

Now I am not getting navigator when custom grid have more than 200 records &
I need to export that 4 Custom Grid Control’s data into CSV file.

Could you help me in this regards? If you have common solution could you share it? 
Or Could you help me with required steps to add "Page Tools" to export data from Custom Grid control?
I look forward a response from your end. Thank you.

Thanks & Regards,
Vijaykumar

Answer (score 0):

Right now there are no immediate plans to implement export CSV functionality in AppSDK2. This may change in the future.

There is [an example](https://github.com/andreano/TaskDelta) of an app that allows to export to Excel spreadsheet. This app shows a view of tasks filtered by Iteration and calculate the Delta between Estimated and Actuals for each task.

This app is not a part of a catalog and is not officially supported or maintained.